# Glass shader has black parts

Tags: shaders, glass

i'm trying to render this glass material but i have these black parts all over the model. Any idea what could be the cause of this ?[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show your Light Paths panel? Posssible related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82643/how-to-get-rid-of-internal-shadows-blackness-in-glass-transparent-refractive-mat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the HDRI below the horizon. Many of these HDRI's have a black 'ground'. Glass will refract all light, so the black ground as well. That is probably where those dark shapes are coming from. Remember, glass only exists because of reflection and refraction, both of which depend heavily on the environment. If something is wrong with the way your glass behaves you probably need to tweak the environment.

Comment: The black parts on the hdri were indeed my problem. Thank you Niels.

Comment: @TrillDanny If the answer solves all the issues, don't forget to mark it as "accepted".