# simulating arrow illusion

Tags: animation

[image]

now i need to simulate the arrow illusion which is,an arrow drawn on a sheet of paper that is put 4 inches behind a glass and then the glass will be filled with water and look at the arrow through the glass we should find that the arrow direction is reversed due to refraction of light(you can check that on youtube). I know how to simulate fluids, but how do i simulate that refraction? How can i simulate what happens to the arrow?

Comment: I have removed your additional question. Please only include one question per post. Open a new post for every question! [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82643/30849) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Model the glass, it is important that it is solid and has a thickness.
2. Simulated or modelled, the fluid has to intersect the glass. However, even with not-intersecting glass, the arrow will refract correctly.
3. Apply a **Refraction BSDF** to both objects (the glass and the fluid) in Cycles Material Nodes.

[image: refraction]

As you can see in the image, the fluid object intersects the glass. The fluid mesh is partially in between the inner and outer wall of the glass.

Comment: i am sorry but i don't understand what do u mean by that the glass should be solid? i understood that i should apply a refraction BSDF to both the glass and the arrow or to the glass and fluid?

Comment: also i am sorry but i don't understand the pic what does the red and purple lines on the glass indicates?

Comment: @user, edited the answer. Please review it. Is it clear now?

Comment: please review my question i guess the problem is reduced now so i need  your help @Leander

Comment: @user It seems you have sucessfully implemented what your question stated. The new situation uncovered a new problem. Please ask a new separate question!